# How do I get total comment count, engagement, weekly post count from instagram?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am using facebook graph api like this `page_id?fields=instagram_accounts{follow_count,media_count},instagram_business_account`. I am getting followers count and media count from instagram but did not get comment count and post count by weekly basis and engagement.